# Request[string] Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this code in Razor:

```
int num1 = int.Parse(Request["ddl" + item.MovieID]);
```

and I get the error: `Input string was not in a correct format.`

How can I fix this problem?

I also tried:

```
string s = "ddl" + item.MovieID;
int num1 = int.Parse(Request[s]);
```

But still I get the same error. This works:

```
int num1 = int.Parse(Request["ddl1"]);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why is the MovieId even part of the Key?

Answer (score 1):

The key may not exist and is returning a null.  Or, the value for that key isn't in an "integer format" - for example, it wouldn't be able to parse "$10.00".

Comment: it's not even trying to get the key because of the "bad format".

Comment: Is MovieID a string?  If not, that could be the problem.  Try: var key = string.Format("ddl{0}", item.MovieID);

Comment: tried this. key does get the value "ddl2" as wanted, but still "bad format". it doesn't make any sense

Comment: Ok the problem is probably with the int.Parse.

Comment: It's kinda weird it's can't be parsed, when I pass Request["ddl" + item.MovieID] to the back-end parse does work on it.

Comment: I suspect it's null, which would be a problem. But all you have to do is render the value to see what the problem is: <span>@Request["key"]</span>

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to this

```
string s = "ddl" + item.MovieID;
string key = Request[s];
int num1 = int.Parse(key);
```

Put a break point on the first line, and step through the code.  If you examine `s` and `key` as you step through the code, you should soon find the issue.

Comment: You cannot add a breakpoint to the Razor view. You can, however, replicate the code elsewhere and, yes, debug the hell out of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error if culture is not correct. Please ensure the string (to be parsed) is as per current thread culture.

Ideally we should use **`int.Parse(data,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`** if data is culture agnostic.